# Limits: Writing a rigorous solution

Tags: limits

I'm going through some past papers, and I'm asked to determine whether $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$$ converges or diverges. The question is fine, I'm just not sure about the level of rigour required. I cannot find any worked solutions that could give me an indication.

I have two variation of my solution:

1) As $k \rightarrow \infty$, it follows that $\frac{1}{k^2} \rightarrow 0$. This in turn means that $e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} \rightarrow 1$, which means as $k$ gets sufficiently large, $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} = \sum_{k=1}^{N} e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} + \sum_{k=N+1}^{\infty} 1^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$$ Since the tail diverges, so does the series. $\square$

2) For all $k \in \mathbb{N}$, it follows that $$1^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} < e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} \iff \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} < \sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)}$$ Since $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} 1^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} = \infty$$ it follows by the comparison test that $$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty} e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} = \infty$$ So the series diverges. $\square$

Is one solution better than the other? Is there an even better way to write a rigorous limit solution? Please give me some feedback.

Comment: $e^{1/k^2}>1$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$,

Comment: It can be much shorter: the general term of a convergent series tends to $0$. This one doesn't.

Comment: If you wanted to make your existing strategies "more rigorous", you can use them to lower-bound the sum of the first $n$ terms. The sum is at least $n$, which becomes arbitrarily large.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It suffices to observe that

$$e^{\left(\frac{1}{k^2}\right)} \rightarrow 1$$

therefore the series doesn’t converge (it is a necessary condition that $a_k \to 0$).

Comment: Great thanks, but can I really use that reasoning? What about the harmonic series? The terms tend to zero, but the series diverges... Or am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: "not $A$ implies not $B$" is not the same as "$A$ implies $B$". (in this example $A$ is "the series converges" and $B$ "its terms tend to zero"). @user9750060

Comment: Good observation. The fact is that “$\sum a_k$ converges $\implies a_k\to 0$” but the converse is not true. From here if $a_k\not \to 0$ we can conclude that the series doesn’t converge.

Comment: In other words we cannot find a convergent series with $a_k\not \to 0$.